Does anyone know how to make confidence intervals appear when using the "estat trendplots" command in Stata (after running "xtdidregress")
The title says it all.
After running a diff-in-diff in Stata with "xtdidregress", I am then creating a graph testing the parallel trends assumption using the command "estat trendplots". However, I cannot make the confidence intervals appear in the graph. Any pointers would be most welcome!
I tried "ci_plot" options from the Stata help file for this command, but nothing worked. Someone seems to have figured this out for R (from what I saw in Stack Overflow).
Here is an example code:
webuse hospdd
xtset hospital
xtdidregress (satis)(procedure), group(hospital) time(month)
estat trendplots



Without a reproducible example -- dataset and complete code that anyone can run -- this reads most like an attempt to get talking to someone who has worked in this area. That's not a a good question for SO.

Apologies—just added an example!

Thanks. That's there for anyone who does this kind of thing (which doesn't include me).

This is not an option because an overlap between the CIs does not always correspond to the failure to reject parallel trends. No overlap means you can reject the null, but only substantial overlap indicates that you cannot, and this can be hard to eyeball from the graph. You may observe scant overlap but then make the wrong conclusion that the trends are parallel. See here for an approx. RoT. Stata is thoughtful in keeping you from making a plot that can be misinterpreted.
I would use estat ptrends to do the formal hypothesis test.
Alternatively, plot the CIs for the DID leads coefficient(s) from the augmented model of equation (2) in the didregress_post methods and formulas pdf and compare those to zero. I think this is actually what estat grangerplot does.
